# Не выводится заголовок категории laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Выдает ошибку при переходе на роут /catalog/{id}. Пытался сделать вывод заголовка соответствующей категории, но видимо что то сделал не так, подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка.

```
            // Роуты
                 Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
                 Route::get('/catalog', 'SiteController@catalog');
                 Route::get('/catalog/{id}', 'SiteController@catalog_page');
                 Route::get('/contacts', 'SiteController@contacts');

           //Контроллеры
                 class SiteController extends Controller
{



public function catalog()
{
    return view('catalog', ['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' => Tovar::all()]);
}
public function catalog_page()
{
    $category = new Menu();
    $category = $category->with('children')->where('id')->get()->toArray();



    return view('catalog_page', ['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' => Tovar::all(),'result' => $category]);
}

public function contacts()
{
    return view('contacts', ['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' => Tovar::all(),]);
}
public function index()
{
    return view('index',['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' => Tovar::all(),]);
 }
}

           // Модель Menu
         <?php

         namespace App;

         use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

         class Menu extends Model
        {
         protected $table = 'menus';
        }
```

Undefined index: title (View: D:\OSPanel\domains\blog\resources\views\catalog_page.blade.php)  -  ошибка

```
      @extends('template')


      @section('content')

      <div class="content__right">

      <h1>{{$result['title']}}</h1>
      </div>

     @endsection
```

Comment: ну так вы показали все кроме самой ошибки ))) и хотите что бы мы ее угадали ?

Comment: Сорри, дописал.

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('catalog_page', ['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' => Tovar::all(),'result' => $category]);
```

title то нету, добавьте

Comment: Добавил, Вы слишком быстры ))

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в получении данных категории:

```
$category = $category->with('children')->where('id')->get()->toArray();
```

Исправьте эту часть кода таким образом:

```
public function catalog_page($id)
{
    $category = Menu::with('children')->find($id)->toArray();
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло...

Comment: Ошибку выдает ту же?

Comment: Внес правки в ответ, попробуйте еще так.

Comment: Call to a member function toArray() on null - вот такую ошибку щас выдает

Comment: Перед получением данных поставьте `dd($id);` что выводится?

Comment: Выводится Url..

Comment: нет, перед 
    `$category = Menu::with('children')->find($id)->toArray();`

Comment: сейчас надо передать это в титл?